# Is it possible to output and display U+2717 (BALLOT X) in the Windows console?

Tags: c#, unicode, console-application

I am attempting to output the unicode character U+2717 (BALLOT X) to the Windows console window from a C# program, and am having no success. No combination of font, output encoding, or anything else seems to work. The font I'm using by default (Consolas) can correctly display this character, as it's the font I'm using in Visual Studio, and Visual Studio correctly displays the character. A nearby character, U+2713 (CHECK MARK) displays correctly, so I think that there's something specific with this character that is preventing it from displaying correctly. What could it be?

Sample (non-working) code:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("✗");
```

Also doesn't work (fails in the same way, i.e. outputs "?"):

```
System.Console.WriteLine("\u2717");
```

I've tried setting various output encodings:

```
System.Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32;
```

- UTF32 throws an exception (The parameter is incorrect.).
- UTF8 outputs a ? in a little box (Consolas font).
- UTF16 outputs a ? in a little box (Consolas font).
- If I don't set the output encoding, I get a normal ? character. By default, OutputEncoding is SBCSCodePageEncoding.

Comment: How about `Console.WriteLine('\u2717');`?

Comment: You to set the output encoding of the console to use Unicode, and use a proper font, like Consolas.

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky here, but I know how to create the character in code, that's not the problem. The problem is, how to DISPLAY it in the console window.

Comment: @leppie: doesn't work. Try it for yourself.

Comment: Yep, I just tried :( Windows 10 promises better Unicode console support I believe.

Comment: Not sure how you get U+2713 showing. Fails for me too :( The ? in a box is just a replacement character.

Comment: The really frustrating thing is that U+2713 works. Aggravating.

Comment: 1) [find a fixed-width font](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2717/fontsupport.htm) that supports this character.  Maybe [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/dejavu_sans_mono/index.htm).  2) [Add the font](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/) to the list of possible console fonts.  Never done it myself, don't know if it would work.

Comment: @dbc: Consolas supports that glyph, as mentioned in the question. Consolas is being used as the console font. Doesn't work.

Comment: @Mark - I'm not 100% sure it does. Visual Studio may have logic to fall back to "MS Mincho" if the selected font can't display the character.  On Win7 at least, Word refuses to display ✗ in Consolas and instead falls back to MS Mincho.  If I use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604855/how-to-determine-which-fonts-contain-a-specific-character/5605240#5605240) to list the fonts supporting ✗, I get Meiryo, Meiryo UI, MS Gothic, MS Mincho, MS PGothic, MS PMincho, MS UI Gothic and Segoe UI Symbol.

Comment: @dbc: it appears you're correct, Consolas *does not* seem to support that character. DejaVu Sans Mono, however, does, and the character appears as it should if that font is chosen. Make it an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

✗ isn't supported by Consolas on my Win7 machine.   If I use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604855/how-to-determine-which-fonts-contain-a-specific-character/5605240#5605240) to list the fonts supporting ✗, I get Meiryo, Meiryo UI, MS Gothic, MS Mincho, MS PGothic, MS PMincho, MS UI Gothic and Segoe UI Symbol.  What I believe is happening is that Visual Studio is falling back on MS Mincho since Consolas lacks the requisite glyph.  Word definitely does this - if I type ✗ into Word I can't change the font to Consolas.

To work around:

1. [Find a fixed-width font](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2717/fontsupport.htm) that supports this character.  For instance [DejaVu Sans Mono does](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/dejavu_sans_mono/index.htm).
2. Install the font.
3. Add the font to the list of possible console fonts using instructions here: [Enable More Fonts for the Windows Command Prompt](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/).
4. Select the font in the console window.