# CMD outputs when using pylanguagetool (Python)

Tags: python, command-line, languagetool

I'm using [pylanguagetool](https://pypi.org/project/pyLanguagetool/), a Python wrapper for [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/), a spelling/grammar correction application. It operates in both Python and Windows command line. It is particularly useful in command line, as it displays outputs in the following manner:

[image]

I'd like to capture this output, preferably in the same format. However, the standard methods of capturing command line outputs appear to generate encoding errors. For example,

```
pylanguagetool Text_01.txt > Text_01_comments.txt
```

generates the following error:

```
    C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python\Grading\HI333\Test>pylanguagetool Text_01.txt > Text_01_comments.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pylanguagetool.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pylanguagetool\__init__.py", line 257, in main
    print_errors(response,
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pylanguagetool\__init__.py", line 166, in print_errors
    print(
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 187, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, start)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\encodings\mbcs.py", line 25, in encode
    return mbcs_encode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode character '\u2717' in position 0: invalid character
```

and writes only the following in the output file:

```
English (US) detected (99% confidence)

Possibly missing comma found.
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

UPDATE: After a suggestion to adopt the following:

```
pylanguagetool --no-color Text_01.txt > Text_01_comments.txt
```

The following error is generated:

```
C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python\Grading\HI333\Test>pylanguagetool --no-color Text_01.txt > Text_01_comments.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pylanguagetool.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pylanguagetool\__init__.py", line 257, in main
    print_errors(response,
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pylanguagetool\__init__.py", line 166, in print_errors
    print(
  File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\encodings\mbcs.py", line 25, in encode
    return mbcs_encode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode character '\u2717' in position 2: invalid character
```

and continues to write the following in the output file:

```
English (US) detected (99% confidence)

Possibly missing comma found.
```

Comment: Looks like there are issues handling the control chars that add color to the output. Try passing the `--no-color` flag?

Comment: The problem persists - similar, if shorter error message: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python\Grading\HI333\Test>pylanguagetool Text_01.txt > Text_01_comments.txt --no-color

Comment: Think you need to place the flag before the input file name: `pylanguagetool --no-color Text_01.txt > Text_01_comments.txt`

Comment: Many thanks for the correction. The problem is persisting, unfortunately. I will post the new error code above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to output and display U+2717 (BALLOT X) in the Windows console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519142/is-it-possible-to-output-and-display-u2717-ballot-x-in-the-windows-console)

Comment: In both cases encoding fails due to cmd.