# Get font in use when multiple font families specified in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts

In WPF I set a style for my control so it has multiple font families specified:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="Helvetica, Arial, Segoe UI" />
</Style>
```

How can I determine which font is actually got selected and is in use for the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this blog post](https://www.mrlacey.com/2021/01/fallback-fonts-in-xaml.html):

> The XAML text renderer [...] uses the specified list (family) of fonts on a character by character basis.

So there is no ‘*font in use for the control*’ as you ask.

To find out which font is used for each character, [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605240/361177) looks a good starting point.

Comment: You can find my test code related to this question [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_70937142).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just having to parse the `FontFamily`'s `Source` property:

```
public static FontFamily GetFirstValid(this FontFamily fontFamily)
{
    return fontFamily?.Source.Split(',')
                     .Select(p => new FontFamily(p))
                     .FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetTypefaces()
                                           .Any(t => t.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out GlyphTypeface glyph)
                                                     && glyph?.CharacterToGlyphMap.Count > 0));
}
```