# Modifying character spacing/width in a TextBox control

Tags: .net, winforms, fonts, textbox, richtextbox

I'm trying to dynamically set the spacing (width) of each character in a TextBox control. I've done tons of reading and I don't believe this is even possible in a regular TextBox. I'm open to the RichTextBox or any other control that can solve this.

To prove that this is possible I opened up Word and I was able to select one character and adjust its spacing and "stretch" it out. I'm looking to achieve the same behavior in my .NET application.

[image: Modified M]

Is there a code sample or control out there that shows how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I can't really think of any other method to do this, other than an owner drawn control; one that inherits the TextBox class, but then one that you control the paint of the characters; as you already know the location of each character, you can specify (if you used fixed with fonts for example) how these things display in the box.  Or you can use a 3rd party control like DevExpress, DevComponents or Telerak.

Comment: You'd have to implement your own control and use Graphics.ScaleTransform() + Graphics.DrawString().  Hard to get the letter spacing right, Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges.  Even harder to make it look good.

Comment: A cheap hack around making your own control might be to use a WebBrowser control - this way you would only need to generate HTML to do what you want.  Not tested, but I think it could work.  You wouldn't be able to type in the control, of course - you would have to split between a work area and display area...at least without extending WebBrowser as you would have to do for TextBox.

Comment: Unfortunately WPF isn't an option for me at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

If you accept to link to some WPF's assemblies (WindowsBase and PresentationCore), you can write a custom TextBox and use it in a WinForms implementation. WPF has some nice classes like the [GlyphTypeFace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (allows to load a font file and build geometries from glyphs), and [GlyphRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphrun.aspx) (which allows to draw a list of glyphs - a text). But we can't use GlyphRun here because we want to be able to modify the geometry of some glyphs. So we need to manually get geometries and transform them.

Here is an example:

The Winforms code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ElementHost allows Winforms to host WPF visual components
        ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
        host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        host.Child = new MyTextBox();
        Controls.Add(host);
    }
```

The custom TextBox code:

```
public class MyTextBox: UIElement
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        const string sampleText = "Sample String";
        const int sampleEmSize = 30;

        GlyphTypeface typeFace = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri("file:///C:/WINDOWS/FONTS/segoeui.ttf"));

        GeometryGroup group = new GeometryGroup();
        group.FillRule = FillRule.Nonzero;

        double x = 0;
        double y = sampleEmSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleText.Length; i++)
        {
            ushort glyphIndex = typeFace.CharacterToGlyphMap[sampleText[i]];
            Geometry glyphGeometry = typeFace.GetGlyphOutline(glyphIndex, sampleEmSize, sampleEmSize).Clone();
            TransformGroup glyphTransform = new TransformGroup();

            if (sampleText[i] == 'm') // this is a sample, we just change the 'm' characte
            {
                const double factor = 2;
                glyphTransform.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(factor, 1));
                glyphTransform.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(x, y));
                x += factor * typeFace.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * sampleEmSize;
            }
            else
            {
                glyphTransform.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(x, y));
                x += typeFace.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * sampleEmSize;
            }

            glyphGeometry.Transform = glyphTransform;
            group.Children.Add(glyphGeometry);
        }

        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Black, null, group);
    }
}
```

And here is the result on the WinForms:

[image]

Of course, there is some work to do, if you want to support edit, but this may get you started.

Comment: Maybe this question/answer can help you also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025740/c-check-for-unsupported-characters-glyphs-in-a-font

Answer (score 0):

for your reference, i've written this code which will let you change the font, fontstyle for each character that you type into a RichTextBox.

```
public int a = 0;
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (a == 0)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(RichTextBox.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold);
            a = 1;
        }
        else if (a == 1)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Georgia",13, FontStyle.Bold);
            a = 2;
        }
        else if (a == 2)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Impact", 11, FontStyle.Italic);
            a = 0;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into Telerik controls for WinForms.  I know they have a large emphasis on style elements.